# how to work UICollectionView in iOS 5

Tags: iphone

IS it work UICollictionview in IOS 5 error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UICollectionView is not directly available in IOS5.

However there is a nice open source control for adding UICollectionView support in IOS5.  Its called PSCollectionView and you can find it here:  [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView)

It is a drop in library that emulates UICollectionView on IOS5 and passes through on IOS6.  Very nice and works very well.

best of luck.

Comment: Do you mean PSTCollectionView, which provides PSUICollectionView?
=> https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView

Comment: thank you for your comment.  I did mean PSTCollectionView.  I updated the link in the answer.  Great Library btw.

Answer (score 5):

Check Availability of [UICollectionView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html)

**Availability** Available in iOS 6.0 and later.

You can go with [PSCollectionView](https://github.com/ptshih/PSCollectionView)

Answer (score 3):

In fact the problem probably isn't due to `UICollectionView` not being available in iOS5. It looks as though you're using constraints in Interface Builder. It is *that* that's causing the problem.

So, two things:

1. Use something like [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView) to add UICollectionView support in iOS5
2. Switch off constraints and revert to using "springs and struts" to resize/relocate your subviews