# rotate images using UICollectionview in iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6, uicollectionview, pstcollectionview

I have used UICollectionView (Like below Image) in **IOS6** is working fine.

Now, i want this in **IOS5**. but "UICollectionview" is not supported by iOs5.

i have triyed using supported library  [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView) but not get success.

So, it is possible to do this in **IOS5**? HOW?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`UICollectionView` is iOS6 only. You can include extra code to check for iOS6 and use your custom class on iOS5. But there is no way to use an actual `UICollectionView` in iOS5.

have look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038847/how-to-work-uicollectionview-in-ios-5)